# Parse string into map Golang

Tags: parsing, dictionary, go

I have a string like A=B&C=D&E=F, how to parse it into map in golang?

Here is example on Java, but I don't understand this `split` part

```
String text = "A=B&C=D&E=F";
Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
for(String keyValue : text.split(" *& *")) {
   String[] pairs = keyValue.split(" *= *", 2);
   map.put(pairs[0], pairs.length == 1 ? "" : pairs[1]);
}
```

Comment: I think what you really want is [`url.ParseQuery`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#ParseQuery).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Maybe what you really want is to parse an HTTP query string, and [`url.ParseQuery`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#ParseQuery) does that. (What it returns is, more precisely, a `url.Values` storing a `[]string` for every key, since URLs sometimes have more than one value per key.) It does things like parse HTML escapes (`%0A`, etc.) that just splitting doesn't. You can find its implementation if you search in [the source of `url.go`](https://golang.org/src/net/url/url.go).

However, if you *do* really want to just split on `&` and `=` like that Java code did, there are Go analogues for all of the concepts and tools there:

- [`map[string]string`](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Map_types) is Go's analog of `Map<String, String>`
- [`strings.Split`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Split) can split on `&` for you. [`SplitN`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#SplitN) limits the number of pieces split into like the two-argument version of `split()` in Java does. Note that there might only be one piece so you should check `len(pieces)` before trying to access `pieces[1]` say.
- [`for _, piece := range pieces`](https://golang.org/ref/spec#For_statements) will iterate the pieces you split.
- The Java code seems to rely on regexes to trim spaces. Go's `Split` doesn't use them, but [`strings.TrimSpace`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#TrimSpace) does something like what you want (specifically, strips all sorts of Unicode whitespace from both sides).

I'm leaving the actual implementation to you, but perhaps these pointers can get you started.

Answer (score 10):

```
import ( "strings" )

var m map[string]string
var ss []string

s := "A=B&C=D&E=F"
ss = strings.Split(s, "&")
m = make(map[string]string)
for _, pair := range ss {
    z := strings.Split(pair, "=")
    m[z[0]] = z[1]
}
```

This will do what you want.

Comment: A few differences from the original Java: 1) this will crash with index out of range when an item is missing a `=`, 2) this doesn't strip spaces around the delimiters, 3) anything after an `=` in the value part is dropped. Fine to do something similar rather than identical, just all bears noting (especially the crash).

Answer (score 0):

There is a very simple way provided by golang `net/url` package itself.

Change your string to make it a url with query params `text := "method://abc.xyz/A=B&C=D&E=F";`

Now just pass this string to `Parse` function provided by `net/url`.

```
import (
    netURL "net/url"
)
```

```
u, err := netURL.Parse(textURL)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
```

Now `u.Query()` will return you a map containing your query params. This will also work for complex types.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a demonstration of a couple of methods:

```
package main

import (
   "fmt"
   "net/url"
)

func main() {
   {
      q, e := url.ParseQuery("west=left&east=right")
      if e != nil {
         panic(e)
      }
      fmt.Println(q) // map[east:[right] west:[left]]
   }
   {
      u := url.URL{RawQuery: "west=left&east=right"}
      q := u.Query()
      fmt.Println(q) // map[east:[right] west:[left]]
   }
}
```

- https://golang.org/pkg/net/url#ParseQuery
- https://golang.org/pkg/net/url#URL.Query